# Enviar push, via php, para todos os usuários

Tags: php, ionic, apache-cordova, firebase, push-notification

Estou trabalhando num projeto com ionic 3 e backend em php/mysql. Na fase atual eu preciso enviar notificações push e optei por trabalhar com o firebase e o plugin phonegap-plugin-push. Instalei e testei via console do firebase e a notificação foi enviada corretamente. Feito isso, cheguei a um modelo em php para envio de notificações sem utilizar o console firebase, mas encontrei uma dificuldade: não sei como enviar uma notificação para todos os dispositivos (e não por id).

Segue o código PHP utilizado:

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
// set only for one for safety
$registrationId = $_GET['id'];
$texto = $_GET['texto'];
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
'title' => 'Notificação',
'body' => $texto,
'icon' => 'myicon',
'sound' => 'default'
);
$fields = array
(
'priority' => 'high',
'to' => $registrationId,
'notification' => $msg
);
$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

Obs. 1: No console firebase tem ambas opções.

Obs. 2: O código acima funciona corretamente quando informado o id.

O que colocar no `'to' => $registrationId,` para que todos os dispositivos recebam a notificação?

Comment: Por que sem informar o ID? sendo que ele é obrigatorio

Comment: Já tentou usar a plataforma OneSignal? Eu utilizo ela e é realmente boa. (https://onesignal.com/)
Se precisar de ajuda para utiliza-la, diz aí que posso ajuda-lo.

Comment: Com ficaria o código para usar a plataforma oneSignal?

Answer (score -2):

No no 'to' => $registrationId deves colocar o token do seu app
no seu projeto Android
acrescente estas linhas no seu mainactivity dentro do oncreate () {}

//este código irá gerar o token no Logcat do Android Studio, coloque o nome TokenApp na pesquisa e verás um código enorme com letras e números

```
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    String token = task.getResult();
                    Log.d("TokenApp", token);
                }
            });
```